# django related object reference not displaying items

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have two models SubCategory and Product i created a listview with model set to SubCategory and reference its related product set in template but items are not being loaded don't know what I have missed

models

```
class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.FloatField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pdt_imgs/')
    sku = models.IntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    discount = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Template in which I tried to reference product items related to subcategories

```
<div class="ps-block__categories">
          <h3>Clothing & <br> Apparel</h3>
          <ul>
            {% for subcategory in object_list %}
              <li><a href="#">{{ subcategory.name }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul><a class="ps-block__more-link" href="#">View All</a>
        </div>
        <div class="ps-block__slider">
          <div class="ps-carousel--product-box owl-slider" data-owl-auto="true" data-owl-loop="true"
            data-owl-speed="7000" data-owl-gap="0" data-owl-nav="true" data-owl-dots="true" data-owl-item="1"
            data-owl-item-xs="1" data-owl-item-sm="1" data-owl-item-md="1" data-owl-item-lg="1" data-owl-duration="500"
            data-owl-mousedrag="off"><a href="#"><img src="{% static 'img/slider/home-3/clothing-1.jpg' %}" alt=""></a><a href="#"><img
                src="{% static 'img/slider/home-3/clothing-2.jpg' %}" alt=""></a><a href="#"><img
                src="{% static 'img/slider/home-3/clothing-3.jpg' %}" alt=""></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ps-block__product-box">
          {%  for product in object.product_set.all  %}  
            <div class="ps-product ps-product--simple">
              <div class="ps-product__thumbnail"><a href="product-default.html"><img src="{{ product.image.url }}"
                    alt=""></a>
                {% if product.discount > 0 %}    
                  <div class="ps-product__badge">-{{ product.discount }}%</div>
                {% endif %}
                
                {% if product.available == False %}
                  <div class="ps-product__badge out-stock">Out Of Stock</div>
                {% endif %}  
                <ul class="ps-product__actions">
                  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Read More"><i
                        class="icon-bag2"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-placement="top" title="Quick View" data-toggle="modal"
                      data-target="#product-quickview"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add to Whishlist"><i
                        class="icon-heart"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Compare"><i
                        class="icon-chart-bars"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="ps-product__container">
                <div class="ps-product__content" data-mh="clothing"><a class="ps-product__title"
                    href="product-default.html">{{ product.name }}</a>
                  <div class="ps-product__rating">
                    <select class="ps-rating" data-read-only="true">
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="1">2</option>
                      <option value="1">3</option>
                      <option value="1">4</option>
                      <option value="2">5</option>
                    </select><span>01</span>
                  </div>
                  <p class="ps-product__price sale">UGX{{ product.price }}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

For now I cant load product items despite trying reference them as related objects of subcategory

Comment: are you passing object_list in your view?

Comment: yes {% for subcategory in object_list %}

Comment: but my {%  for product in object.product_set.all  %}  is outside the above loop i hope thats not the cause